# DXGI Desktop Duplication causes stuttering with FreeSync/G-Sync

Tags: c++, desktop-application, dxgi, desktop-duplication

Using DXGI Desktop duplication with FreeSync/G-Sync monitor causes stuttering in full screen games. It happens in games which are in the "borderless fullscreen" mode by Windows 10 (you can check it e.g. when you change volume, you see the slider in the left top corner even in game).

I tried the sample desktop duplication and also tried to update the DuplicateOutput1 function. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Desktop-Duplication-Sample-da4c696a
Tested e.g. with Overwatch.

From Windows 10 1809 on Microsoft changed how the games run in fullscreen, so DDupl is almost unusable while playing since then.
Didn't anyone find a solution for this?
Thank you.

Comment: Does desktop duplication capture torn images, or the physical monitor displays artifacts when desktop duplication session is active?

Comment: The physical monitor is tearing, captured image is OK.
By tearing I mean like skipping frames or "low FPS", better word is probably stuttering, I wasn't able to find this word when I wrote it.
I edited it in the post for better meaning...